# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 with odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

I have a date field in form that allows the users to enter a date which presumably the deadline of a task and I want to have difference between today with deadline and concern of:
1.if the date has passed, then show 'overdue'
2.if not, then show the number of days left the given date and add text that say 'the left day  are {%results of difference days%}'
which field type can aggregate integer with text

```
from odoo import models, fields
from odoo import api
from datetime import datetime


class todotask(models.Model):
    _name='todo.task'
    _description='to manage your job tasks'

    name=fields.Char('Description', required=True)
    gov_deprt_id=fields.Many2many('res.partner',string='Gov 
                 Department')
    company=fields.Many2one('res.partner',
            string='Work For')
    start_date=fields.Date('Start Date')
    deadline_date=fields.Date('Deadline')
    is_done=fields.Boolean('Done?')
    note=fields.Text('Note')
    amount=fields.Float('Cost Amount')
    remaining_days=fields.Integer(string="Remaining Days")

@api.onchange('start_date', 'deadline_date', 'remaining_days')

def calculate_date(self):
     while self.start_date and self.deadline_date:
        d1 = datetime.strptime(str(self.start_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
        d2 = datetime.strptime(str(self.deadline_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
        d3 = d2 - d1
        self.remaining_days ="{} and {}".format("tttt", str(d3.days))
```

Comment: try to int(d3.days) instead of str(d3.days). If don't work, you should do what @travisw said in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a string value to your `Integer` field. Change `remaining_days` to be a `Char` field an you won't have an issue.

```
remaining_days = fields.Char(string="Remaining Days")
```